# treeview 3-state and 2-state checkboxes on different nodes

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, treeview

I have to create a **treeview** control in a class that inherits from **CTreeCtrl**. After many tries, I have created **3-state checkboxes** for every node. And here comes my question - I need **some child nodes to have only 2 states** (checked or unchecked). Any clue on how can I reach that goal? I tried to add an `if` statement to change the behavior like this:

```
else if (itemState == INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(3))
{
    SetItemState(hItem, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
```

And it’s working! Except **when an element is "selected"**, then it’s like ignoring every behavior I did in the `OnLButtonClick` event.

Is there some other event I don’t know about? Is there an easier way to get a 2-state checkbox only on some nodes and not others?

This is all i use to control the tree

```
void CSelDepTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    UINT Flags = 0;
    HTREEITEM hItem = HitTest(point, &Flags);
    if ((NULL != hItem) && (TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON & Flags))
    {
        auto itemText = GetItemText(hItem);
        if (itemText.Left(1) == "C") {
            if ((nFlags & (MK_SHIFT | MK_CONTROL)) || NULL == GetParentItem(hItem)) {
                SetCheckChild(hItem, GetCheck(hItem));
            }
        }

        if (itemText.Left(1) == "L") {
            if ((nFlags & (MK_SHIFT | MK_CONTROL)) || NULL == GetParentItem(hItem)) {
                SetCheckChild(hItem, GetCheck(hItem));
            }
        }

        if (itemText.Left(1) == "S") {
            auto itemState = GetItemState(hItem, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
            if (itemState == INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1))
            {
                SetItemState(hItem, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
            }
            else if (itemState == INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2))
            {
                SetItemState(hItem, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
            }
            else if (itemState == INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(3))
            {
                SetItemState(hItem, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are better off not using native checkbox states at all. Just use your own imagelist assigned to the treeview, containing 3 images that look like checkboxes (which you can get from the OS, using `DrawFrameControl()` or `DrawThemeBackground()` - see [Rendering standard Windows elements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050801-11/?p=34763)), and set each node’s image index as needed, such as in a mouse click handler.

Comment: Hello, actually i didnt manage to use native 3 state, instead im using just like you said my own imageList. Still my problem is that i need have elements with 2 states (2 images max) but when item is being selected (is lighted by blue) OnLMouseButton its not the even its called when i click on checkbox of this node.

Comment: then you are going to have to show your actual code. I've used this technique before and it works just fine, but I don't use `CTreeCtrl` for it.

Comment: I have edit main post and add everything i use to control treeview